# How can I get element value from XPathNodeIterator?

Tags: c#, xml, c#-2.0, xpathnodeiterator

When I try to code as this,

```
XPathNodeIterator it;

string selectStr = "Equipment/Group/item";
it = nav.Select(selectStr);
while (it.MoveNext())
{
    String strVal = "";
    if (it.Current.HasChildren)
    {
        strVal = it.Current.Value.ToString(); // get wrong value here. I want to get 'COM' and 'MD'
    }
}
```

My Xml File as this

```
<Equipment xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <License licenseId="" licensePath=""/>
  <Group>
    <item>
      <key>COM</key>
      <value>
        <format>10</format>
        <value>0</value>
      </value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>MD</key>
      <value>
        <format>20</format>
        <value>test</value>
      </value>
    </item>
.....
```

I found when I use `while` method to loop all the xml file is very convenient.

But I don't know how to establish the relation to get element value when I defined an XPathNodeIterator as above?

Actually, I need read the whole Xml file with the aid of XPathNodeIterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to start a new iterator for each subnode selecting only the subitems. `XPathNodeIterator` and *XPath* in general is more geared towards **extracting** data from xml. If you want to read the whole XML file, you should consider [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) (very fast, forward only) or [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) (easy to use).